# tapply - creating NA?

Tags: r, plyr, tapply

I'm trying to calculate the mean number of unique fruits per person (my usual practice data). This works perfectly well with both these lines of code:

```
with(df, tapply(fruit, names, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))->uniques
sum(uniques)/length(unique(df$names))

aggregate(df[,"fruit"], by=list(id=names), FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))->d1
sum(d1$x)/length(unique(df$names))
```

My problem is that when I use the code on my real data it doesn't work. My real data is prescribing data, where I want mean number of unique drugs per person. With the tapply code, it has appeared to create brand new patient ids that do not exist in the original df. it has also given back 1000s of NA values. There are no missing values in my id column and none in drug_code column either

```
with(dt3, tapply(drug_code, id, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))->uniques    

head(uniques)
                   uniques
Patient HAI0000001      NA
Patient HAI0000003      NA
Patient HAI0000008      NA
Patient HAI0000010      NA
Patient HAI0000014      NA
Patient HAI0000020      NA

table(dt3$id=="Patient HAI0000001")  ##checking to see if HA10000001 occurs in original df. the dim of df are 228954 rows and 5 cols

FALSE 
228954
```

For the aggregate code I get an error:

```
aggregate(dt3[,"drug_code"], by=list(id=id), FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))->d1

Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

I don't understand whats happening. My real data is similar to my practice data in that it has an id col and has a drug/fruit column. there are no missing data in either df. I know lapply is better for dataframes, but I don't necessarily need a df back. And in any case the tapply code works on practice data which is a df. Does anyone have any idea of what is happening here?

Practice DF:

```
 names<-as.character(c("john", "john", "john", "john", "john", "mary", "mary","mary","mary","mary", "jim", "sylvia","ted","ted","mary", "sylvia", "jim", "ted", "john", "ted"))
dates<-as.Date(c("2010-07-01",  "2010-09-01", "2010-11-01", "2010-12-01", "2011-01-01", "2010-08-12",  "2010-11-11", "2010-05-12",  "2010-12-03", "2010-07-12",  "2010-12-21", "2010-02-18",  "2010-10-29", "2010-08-13",  "2010-11-11", "2010-05-12",  "2010-04-01", "2010-05-06",  "2010-09-28", "2010-11-28" ))
fruit<-as.character(c("kiwi","apple","banana","orange","apple","orange","apple","orange", "apple", "apple", "pineapple", "peach", "nectarine", "grape", "melon", "apricot", "plum", "lychee", "watermelon", "apple" ))
df<-data.frame(names,dates,fruit)
```

example of real data:

```
head(dt3)
        id         quantity   date_of_claim drug_code  index
1  Patient HAI0000560        1    2009-10-15 R03AC02 2010-04-06
2  Patient HAI0000560        1    2009-10-15 R03AK06 2010-04-06
3  Patient HAI0000560       30    2009-10-15 R03BB04 2010-04-06
4  Patient HAI0000560       30    2009-10-15 A02BC01 2010-04-06
5  Patient HAI0000560       50    2009-10-15 M02AA15 2010-04-06
6  Patient HAI0000560       30    2009-10-15 N02BE51 2010-04-06
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case you are asking fir a single number: the mean of all the individual lengths of a particular vector `(unique(fruits))` within patient-id. This shws you first the indivdual unique counts and then the mean function result:

```
> with(df,  tapply(fruit, names, function(x) length(unique(x)) ))
   jim   john   mary sylvia    ted 
     2      5      3      2      4 
> mean ( with(df,  tapply(fruit, names, function(x) length(unique(x)) )) )
[1] 3.2
```

I would comment that your test for containment of a particular value in your code above had a trailing space which might have caused problems. `"string "` will not equal `"string"`. I have put a copy of the use the trim function in `pkg::gdata` in my .Rprofile file to make it easier for me to handle this possibility.

Comment: Hi Dwin, thank you for responding. The trailing space was just a mistake on my part when transferring the code, it's not the cause of the problem. Using the mean function is better than what I was doing - but this isn't the problem. The problem is tapply. It is creating all these Nas where it shouldn't be. it works fine on dummy data, I can't figure out why it won't work on real data. dummydata is equal to real data in that all variables in the tapply code are factor variables. there are no Nas in real data to begin with, so I don't know why tapply is making them.

Comment: hang on - think I've figured something out - - stay tuned

Comment: If you would post `dput(head(dt3))` we could offer better assistance.

Comment: ok, here's the answer! I made my real DF (dt3), by cutting it from another bigger parent DF. therefore, the levels of id in dt3 remained the same as the parent DF. thats where all the Nas are coming from. The solution is quite simple.........sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)/length(unique(dt3$hai_dispense_number)). I'm sticking with this - mean(x, na.rm=TRUE) takes too long! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks again DWin - when I made the dput to put on here the solution was even more evident.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but wouldn't a simple `tapply` work here?  The line below calculates the number of different fruits per person

```
x=tapply(df$fruit,df$names,function(x){length(unique(x))})
```

And then `mean(x)` would give you the average across people?

Comment: Hi slammaster - thanks for reply. see my response to Dwin, the mean function is not my question - the question refers to why tapply is creating Nas in my real df. Can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Hi again slammaster - i figured it out - see solution which I put in my conversation with DWin. Funnily the mean(x, na.rm=TRUE) was taking too long to  run so I'm sticking with sum/length. Thanks for your help!